# Is there a design pattern with the purpose to avoid a signature confusion?

Tags: design-patterns, api-design

In order to avoid a confusion within a method signature comprised of the same types, a class can be introduced to make it distinguishable from others.

Let me support a text description with an example in Java.

E.g., from:

```
public void foo(String bar, String baz, String qux, String quux);
```

to:

```
public void foo(Bar bar, Baz baz, Qux qux, Quux quux);
```

with the class definitions like the following one:

```
public final class Bar {

    private String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

*Is there a name for a such design pattern or a similar one?*

Comment: It's not a design pattern, it's the third rule of object calisthenics : wrap all primitives and strings.

Comment: That's not a design pattern, it's a code smell. Don't have methods that take four parameters of the same type, and definitely don't wrap each of them in a new type - that's not less confusing, just differently confusing. Have you considered using a Builder pattern (the Bloch one, not the GoF one)?

Comment: @EricStein, surely, that's an exaggerated example.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard, thank you! Will have a look at those rules.

Comment: This is a common pattern in Haskell sometimes called "wrapper types". Of course, this is in the case that there is some meaning being indicated by these "wrapper types". Making up random types would indicate a serious design issue. [This article](http://degoes.net/articles/newtypes-suck) does a good job giving some of the good and bad aspects of this (albeit biased in one direction as the author's complaint is that it doesn't go far enough). In a different vein, you absolutely should not have setters. That changes the semantics significantly.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard The presentation (https://fr.slideshare.net/rdohms/bettercode-phpbenelux212alternate/23-Ad_ap_OC_3_te) actually says "Wrap primitive types and string, if it has behavior" (slide 23). That's not the case here.

Comment: @EricStein, regarding Bloch's Builder, it's semantically richer than just passing nameless parameters in a given order, although I don't think that pattern enforces the obligatory nature of non-default parameters. One, for instance, may build an object like: new foo().withBar(bar).andBaz(baz); Syntactically correct, but logically wrong.

Comment: @JesusAlonsoAbad You can manipulate builder to require parameters by returning objects instead of the main builder class which push you down a required path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible cases here, and unfortunately your example is too simplified to tell which one of the two applies in your question:

1. The parameter types represent some domain concept.
2. The parameters actually *are* `String`s.

In case #1, the types shouldn't have been `String`s to begin with, they should have been domain types, such as `FirstName`,  `LastName`, or `Address`. [Darren Hobbs calls this the *Tiny Types Pattern*](https://darrenhobbs.com/2007/04/11/tiny-types/), but really, it's just correct design.

In case #2, what you are proposing is just wrong. The parameters are `String`s, so their type should be `String`.

However, at least in case #2, it is highly likely that this piece of code violates some other guideline of good design and is, for example, doing too much work. Or, the parameters actually have a relationship with each other and shouldn't be separate parameters but rather an object.

I challenge you to give a *real* example of a method that takes 4 `String`s as parameters and isn't violating good design somewhere. You might want to read the [discussion about the *Zero, One, Infinity Rule* on the Wiki](http://wiki.c2.com/?ZeroOneInfinityRule). [@Steve Chamaillard](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/367687/is-there-a-design-pattern-with-the-purpose-to-avoid-a-signature-confusion#comment803078_367687) mentioned the relationship to [Object Callisthenics](http://xpteam.com/jeff/writings/objectcalisthenics.rtf) in his comment.

Note: [As @Derek Elkins mentioned in his comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/367687/is-there-a-design-pattern-with-the-purpose-to-avoid-a-signature-confusion#comment803089_367687), the fact that you made your wrapper types mutable whereas the original type (`String`) is immutable, *completely* changes the semantics of the code! In my answer, I am assuming this mistake is corrected and the setter removed. (Veering off into very opinionated territory here, I suggest that you should never have setters, period.)

Comment: Jörg, thank you for a comprehensive answer, the refereed articles are nice! doesn't look like a feasible task to provide a example of a method that takes four strings as parameters and doesn't break some good design principle. Though, the mutability aspect mentioned in your answer is opinionated, it looks valid for me as well.